# Variable Scope issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

It may be because this has been a long day... but I am having with some basic scope issues.  I am creating an object, passing it in to a delegate method, and adding it to an array wihin the method.

When I check the value of device within the method, it contains the device information.
Here is the code for the delegate function in the class that registered the delegate:

```
- (void) newAmeriscanDevice:(AmeriscanDevice *)device {
    if (!self.deviceArray)
        self.deviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // add the newly created device...
    [self.deviceArray addObject:device];
}
```

This method is within the same class of the earlier function.  The deviceArray shows that it contains one object (supposed to the the driver object from above).  When I look at the value of the device object in here, it is always 0x0.

```
- (void) endDevices:(NSNumber *)numberOfDevices {

    // get out of here is there is no device in the device array
    if (!self.deviceArray)
        return;

    // lets sort the array by order of the devices sort order
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    // the array should now be sorted correctly...
    [self.deviceArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];

    // we now have data -- so.... lets reload the table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

So.... any idea on how to make sure the object in the array retains its values?

Thanks All

Mike

Comment: Can you show us the class header?

Comment: `self.deviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is most probably a leak unless `deviceArray` is an `assign` property. If it isn't, do `self.deviceArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: It's not possible for an array to hold a nil (0x0) value.  How are you getting the value out in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks Kendall -- I reevaluated and determined that my assessment was incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

write code some thing like this

```
 - (void) newAmeriscanDevice:(AmeriscanDevice *)device {
        if (!self.deviceArray)
        {
            NSMutableArray *tempArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.deviceArray=tempArray;
   [tempArray release];
     }


        [self.deviceArray addObject:device];





    }
```

And check some where you are releasing the array or any reference which having the same location(any other array you have released in which you copy the array by using '=' operator).release it in dealloc.

Comment: This won't compile as the variable scope of `tempArray` is the `if` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with my assessment.  I was looking at the debugger values when hovering over the array.  It would show that there was one object and the object pointer was 0x0. I changed the code:

```
- (void) endDevices:(NSNumber *)numberOfDevices {

    // get out of here is there is no device in the device array
    if (!self.deviceArray)
        return;

    NSLog(@"Array Count: %i", [self.deviceArray count]);
    for (id object in self.deviceArray) {
        if (object == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Nil Object");
        } else {
            AmeriscanDevice *dev = (AmeriscanDevice *)object;
            NSLog(@"Device: %@", [dev description]);
        }

    }

    // lets sort the array by order of the devices sort order
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    // the array should now be sorted correctly...
    [self.deviceArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];

    // we now have data -- so.... lets reload the table
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Once I changed this code, it showed that the object in the array was in face the proper type object.

My problem was in the display of a table.  Apparently the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not being called in the table when I called the reloadData or when the view is first shown.  I created this table view using xcode 4, so I am heading into the xib file to see whats not linked :)